# Calculate specific angle between two lines

Tags: python

I have some problem with math today :) Could you tell me how should I calculate P angle?

[image]

I know first and last point of each line. So I have:

```
L1 = [(10,10),(15,15)]
L2 = [(15,15),(20,8)]
```

But I don't have idea how calculate this angle. If I should be more specific I need to know cos of this angle.

Comment: you're on the wrong side for this kind of question: math.stackexchange is [this way](https://math.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken from the answer on this [forum](https://python-forum.io/Thread-finding-angle-between-three-points-on-a-2d-graph?pid=63842#pid63842).

We directly use `math.atan2` to get the angle in radians from and convert them to degrees. After that we can use it as we want.

Remember to convert the `angle` in degrees to radians before using `math.cos`

```
import math


def angle3pt(a, b, c):
    """Counterclockwise angle in degrees by turning from a to c around b
        Returns a float between 0.0 and 360.0"""
    ang = math.degrees(
        math.atan2(c[1] - b[1], c[0] - b[0]) - math.atan2(a[1] - b[1], a[0] - b[0]))
    return ang + 360 if ang < 0 else ang


L1 = [(10, 10), (15, 15)]
L2 = [(15, 15), (20, 8)]

angle = 180 - angle3pt(L1[0], L1[1], L2[1])

print(angle)
print(math.cos(math.radians(angle)))

# Output
99.46232220802563
-0.1643989873053573
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a maths question than anything else, but anyway here's a Python solution using the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product):

```
import math

def get_angle(line1, line2):
    # Get directional vectors
    d1 = (line1[1][0] - line1[0][0], line1[1][1] - line1[0][1])
    d2 = (line2[1][0] - line2[0][0], line2[1][1] - line2[0][1])
    # Compute dot product
    p = d1[0] * d2[0] + d1[1] * d2[1]
    # Compute norms
    n1 = math.sqrt(d1[0] * d1[0] + d1[1] * d1[1])
    n2 = math.sqrt(d2[0] * d2[0] + d2[1] * d2[1])
    # Compute angle
    ang = math.acos(p / (n1 * n2))
    # Convert to degrees if you want
    ang = math.degrees(ang)
    return ang

line1 = [(10, 10), (15, 15)]
line2 = [(15, 15), (20,  8)]

print(get_angle(line1, line2))
# 99.46232220802563
```